# How to properly link system library to ROS node

Tags: ros2, colcon, linking, target-link-libraries

I've written a simple ROS2 package with a single node, which I link to a system library (no `pkg-config` or CMake find module available) directly:

```
# ...
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/test.cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:/usr/local/include/Aria>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)

ament_target_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} rclcpp geometry_msgs std_msgs sensor_msgs)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Aria)
```

`colcon` is able to build the package successfully (no linking errors), but the compiled and installed binaries (under `/build` and `/install`) can't find the correct library:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libAria.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

even though it has been installed on the default system libraries:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 81639772 Oct 10 23:15 libAria.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 Oct 10 23:15 libAria.so -> libAria.so.3.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 Oct 10 23:15 libAria.so.3 -> libAria.so.3.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 48748760 Oct 10 23:15 libAria.so.3.0.0
```

How do I configure the project so that the path to the library is properly set?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! It seems there is no compilation error. The error you have reported is a runtime error. Please make sure to source the ROS distro and ROS workspace. Furthermore, please try setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.